# Getting values from multiple rasters that overlap polygon using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.7

I have a series of rasters from consecutive years that represent different levels of fire severity. Some of these rasters have pixels that overlap each other in the different years. I have a set of polygons that represent specific species' habitat and I need to see what percent of each polygon is affected by different levels of fire severity.

For example, my rasters have values ranging from around -11000 to 3000 and I only want to see how much of 115-308, 308-643, and 643+ are in each polygon. I would like to just get rid of everything below 115 but the Reclassify tool is not updating the attribute field like I though it was supposed to, but instead creates a new TIFF with only 4 values and rows.

How can I do this?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SetNull](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/set-null.htm) to get rid of all the cells below 115 and then reclassify the output raster into three classes as you explained  in your question.

In Field calculator or SetNull Tool in ArcToolBox you can write the following:

```
SetNull("YourRaster", "YourRaster", "VALUE < 115")
```

Then reclassify the output raster from `SetNull` into the other three classes using Reclassify tool.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using the Setnull tool without success. I'm probably using it wrong and am getting  Error "Set Null [000000_12301899]", Output raster: <empty>.  Not sure why the raster would come out as empty. I decided just to Reclassify everything under 115 as part of the set. It might be useful later.

Comment: Are your rasters all in the exact same projected coordinate system? Sometimes having them in different coordinate systems will cause empty output errors even if they line up well when projected on the fly.